# Is # of characters in a redis key directly incremental to memory required?

Tags: redis

Does redis allocate memory like memcached for keys, in which as long as a key fits in a 'memory slab' of length X, there is no incremental memory required between say the 'foo' key and the 'foo2' key? Or, is the amount of memory required monotonically increasing each time an additional character is added to the key?

What about for the value? Is it also monotonically increasing or subject to the 'slab allocator' concept in redis?

Answer (score 0):

No. Redis is a bit wasteful when it comes to memory. Because of it's design it's very hard for the server to know how much memory it's consuming.

Also, because of 2.x's release which includes the new VM (virtual memory, not to be confused with virtual machine), it takes up more space than actually needed.

You'll find a lot of detailed information about these issues on Antirez's blog: http://antirez.com/